# How prove this matrix inequality $\det(B)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ such
$a_{ij}>0$ and $\det(A)>0$.

Defining the matrix $B:=(a_{ij}^{\frac{1}{n}})$, show that $\det(B)>0?$.

This problem is from my friend, and I have considered sometimes, but I can't. Thank you

Comment: Your friend has fun problems. But this one is only true for $n=1$ and $n=2$ I think.

Comment: You need to change friends: they keep on tricking you.

Comment: @julien: With $n$, you seem to mean the (row) size of the matrix, I suppose.

Comment: @ccorn: That is in the question all right.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Oh yes, thanks. I overlooked that. Well for $2\times2$ matrices, an arbitrary positive exponent would work. For matrix size $3\times3$, there exist sign discrepancies with exponent $\frac{1}{2}$ as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is false. Counterexample:
$$
B=\pmatrix{2&2&2\\ 3&4&2\\ 3&1&4},\ A=B\circ B\circ B=\pmatrix{8&8&8\\ 27&64&8\\ 27&1&64},\ \det(B)=-2,\ \det(A)=7000.
$$

**Edit.** However, if $B$ is positive definite, the *converse* of your statement is true. More specifically, suppose $B$ is positive definite (whether it is entrywise positive is unimportant) and $A$ is the $n$-fold Hadamard product of $B$ (i.e. $A=(b_{ij}^n)$). Then $\det(A)>0$. This is because for positive semidefinite matrices $X$ and $Y$, we have $\det(X\circ Y)\ge\det(X)\det(Y)$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much!+1

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}27&8&1\\1&1&\epsilon\\8&\epsilon&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ is very small.

Answer (score 3):

It is **false** when $n\ge 3$. Counter-example: for $x>0$ small, let

$$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}8 & (1+3x)^3 & 1\\ 1 & (1+x)^3 & 1 \\ x^3 & 1& 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then

$$B(x)=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1+3x & 1\\ 1 & 1+x & 1 \\ x & 1& 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Direct calculation shows that when $x>0$ is small enough, 
$$\det A(x)=15x+O(x^2)>0,\quad \det B(x)=-x+O(x^2)<0.$$