# Matrix determinant inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

Knowing that $A$ and $B$ are $2$ matrices of $2\times2$ with elements on $\mathbb{R}$, we have to prove that $\det(A^2+B^2)\ge\det(AB-BA)$
I tried calculating it directly and got nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm pretty much new to this site and also quite tired right now.

Comment: Answered in the answer provided by user1551 in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756373/determinant-inequality-deta2b2a-b2-ge-3-detab-ba