# Two square matrices with the same minimial polynomial are similar for $n=5$ or $n=6$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that $m_A(x)=m_B(x)=(x-\lambda)^k$ and such that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $A$ equals to the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $B$.
a. Prove that for $n=5$ or $n=6$- $A$ and $B$ are similar
b. Find an example for $n=7$ for which $A$ and $B$ are NOT similar

My main question here is whether I should try proving it for $n=5$ and $n=6$ seperately? Or should I try proving it for any $n$ and then observe that it holds only for $n=5$ or $n=6$?
Plus, any hints or suggestion regarding my main question or the question above will be welcome

Answer (score 2):

For n = 7 consider jordan blocks $(3,2,2)$ and $(3,3,1)$ both these have algebraic and geometric multiplicity $3$, but are not similar. That is, consider matrices $A, B$ such that,

$\chi_A = (x- \lambda)^3(x- \lambda)^3(x- \lambda)^1$ and $\chi_B = (x- \lambda)^3(x- \lambda)^2(x- \lambda)^2$

For $n > 7$ append rest to these jordan blocks as i.e. blocks $(3,2,2,1, \dots ,1)$ and $(3,3,1,1, \dots ,1)$ to get examples of non-similar matrices. For the case of $n = 5$ and $n = 6$, we can list out the possible Jordan blocks and show that this kind of a configurations are not possible. This is not an elegent proof.

Comment: What are $(3,2,2)$ and $(3,3,1)$? There is only one eigenvalue as far as I understand the question.  
And could you explain further what can I do for $n=5,6$ that I cannot for $n=7$?

Comment: For matrix A, let $\chi_A(x) = \prod(x-\lambda)^{k_i}$, It boils down to 2 different groups of natural numbers $(k_1, \dots, k_m), k_i \ge k_{i+1}$, (m is the geometric multiplicity of matrix and $k_1$, the algebraic multiplicity), such that $\sum k_i = n$. In the case of $n = 5$ we will not be able to find two such groups $k^{(1)}_i$ and $k^{(2)}_i$ such that $m^{(1)} = m^{(2)}$ and $k^{(1)}_1 = k^{(2)}_1$.

Answer (score 0):

What is a stake here is the collection (multiset) of sizes of Jordan blocks (all for the unique eigenvalue$~\lambda$) that occur; these must be identical for the matrices to be similar. Being a multiset, order does not matter, so we may arrange the sizes in weakly decreasing order. What is fixed is the sum $n$ of the sizes, and the largest size$~k$, as well as the number$~d$ of (nonzero) sizes, which is the geometric multiplicity. It is easy to see that these informations determine the multiset if one of $k\leq2$ or $d\leq 2$ or $k+d\leq n$ holds. Therefore an example of non-similar matrices requires $k\geq3$ and $d\geq3$ and $n\geq k+l+1\geq 7$. Thus the matrices must be similar if $n\leq6$. For $n=7$, Jordan normal forms with Jordan blocks having sizes $(3,3,1)$ respectively $(3,2,2)$ gives an example of non-similar matrices, for $k=d=3$.

See also [What are examples of two non-similar invertible matrices with same minimal and characteristic polynomial and same dimension of each eigenspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049677/18880) and [How can one find Jordan forms, given the characteristic and minimal polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359136/18880) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/577948/18880).